How to test an iOS app with Meta Ads implemented without having it on the App Store?
I am working on a demo of an iOS app that has Meta Ads (formerly Facebook Ads) integrated, and I need to test it. The issue is that my app is not yet published on the App Store, and I’m wondering if it's possible to test Meta Ads in my app before it’s available publicly.
If this is possible, could someone guide me on the steps I need to follow to test Meta Ads in my iOS app without needing to publish it on the App Store?
I tried making meta developer account added app there , setup Audience Network obvious without AppStore URL and payment method but got my Placement ID.
I tried using that placement ID to show app but it gives error "No Fill"
**code i wrote to show ad-> **
var adView: FBAdView?
adView = FBAdView(
placementID: "Placement_ID",
adSize: kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner,
rootViewController: self
)
adView?.delegate = self
                  // Add banner to view
                  if let adView = adView {
                      adView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50)
                      self.view.addSubview(adView)
                      adView.loadAd()
                  }

//getting this response
Error Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=1001 "No fill" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=null, NSLocalizedDescription=No fill, FBAdErrorDetailKey={
msg = "No fill";
}}
Do i need to edit placement id or do I need Bidding in meta ads or what my approach is lacking?
